# report last column that satisfies condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am working in R and trying to figure out how to report the last column that satisfies a condition. My data looks something like this:

```
 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
 .00  .01  .03  .04
 .00  .07  .02  .18
```

I want to be able to append a column that notes the last (furthest right) column (1,2,3,4) that has a value that satisfies a condition (e.g., <.05). So the first row would be reported as 4 while the second row would report a 3.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Use `max.col` with `ties.method = 'last'`.

```
df$result <- max.col(df < 0.05, ties.method = 'last')
df
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 result
#1    0 0.01 0.03 0.04      4
#2    0 0.07 0.02 0.18      3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0, 0), Col2 = c(0.01, 0.07), Col3 = c(0.03, 
0.02), Col4 = c(0.04, 0.18)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Is there a `min.col`?

Comment: There is no `min.col` but you can do `max.col(-df)` which will work same as `min.col`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option (but the `max.col` method by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66898757/12158757) is more recommended than this)

```
df$result <- with(
  data.frame(which(df < 0.05, arr.ind = TRUE)),
  tapply(col, row, max)
)
```